# Load google chart library with only one script tag,

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to load google chart library and use it from only one script tag. 
Here is example of my code. When I loaded google API with separate script 
everything working properly. But I want to use just one script if it is 
possible.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>one script tag test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Here I'm creating a script object and
      // load jsapi
      var scr = document.createElement("script");
      scr.setAttribute("src","https://www.google.com/jsapi");
      document.head.appendChild(scr);

      // here i wait until 
      // google object appears. 
      (function waitForGoogleLoad() {
            if(typeof google == 'undefined') {
                setTimeout(waitForGoogleLoad, 0);
            } else {
                processChart();
            }
      })();

      function processChart() {
          // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
          google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

          // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
          // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
          // draws it.
          function drawChart() {
            // Create the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data.addRows([
              ['Mushrooms', 3],
              ['Onions', 1],
              ['Olives', 1],
              ['Zucchini', 1],
              ['Pepperoni', 2]
            ]);

            // Set chart options
            var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                           'width':400,
                           'height':300};

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would be very grateful for any ideas and recommendations.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to use the autoloader syntax in the script tag.  That allows you to avoid any issues with waiting for the script to load and calling the google loader from inside another function:

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.setAttribute("src",'https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[{"name":"visualization","version":"1","packages":["corechart"],"callback":"drawChart"}]}');
document.head.appendChild(scr);
function drawChart() {
    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', 3],
        ['Onions', 1],
        ['Olives', 1],
        ['Zucchini', 1],
        ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
        'width':400,
        'height':300
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/G9PKE/